# What does こゆびくらい mean?

Tags: translation

What does こゆびくらい mean? I found this word in a children"s book.

The complete sentence is:

> むかし むかし こどもが いない おじいさんと おかあさんが かみさまに おねがいを すると **こゆびくらい**の おとこのこが うまれました

From this I understand:

> A long time ago and Grandfather and Grandmother that couldn`t have child so crave god...

Comment: The direct object of "crave" in English is what you want (what you ask for), not whom you ask, so they rather prayed to the gods, or begged gods, but craved a child.

Comment: Where are you guys getting "crave" from?

Comment: 小指 means little finger. Origin of the name is, A long ago, applied external medicine by using a little finger.

Comment: @macraf  thanks for the help I use crave because I don't know other word in English :P,

Comment: so a better translate could be A long time ago and grandfather and grandmother I could not have child, they begged God so born about the size of a little finger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

小指{こゆび} is a "little finger"

くらい indicates an approximate quantity or size (in this case)

So together with の they mean "about the size of a little finger" and refer to the boy (おとこのこ), who was born.